# How to parse this simple JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have been learning parsing json data in Android. I was able to parse the json data in the example which I was following. In order to test my self I started to parse some new json data. I came across this json data below:

```
    {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

And I am not able to parse it :(

Below is my code to parse json:

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url){
    JSONObject receivedJSON = null;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode != 200){
            return null;
        }
        //Getting stream of data returned from the server using InputStream
        InputStream streamReceived = response.getEntity().getContent();
        //Reading stream of data using BufferedReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(streamReceived));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        //Reading each line of the received data
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line);
        }
        streamReceived.close();
        //Converting the data read into String using StringBuilder
        String jsonData = builder.toString();
        //Converting String into JSONObject
        receivedJSONData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //returning the JSONObject
    return receivedJSON;
}
```

And in my MainActivity I am getting the JSONObject and accordingly getting information from it. Here is how I am doing it:

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonParser.getJSONFromURL(twitterURL);
    JSONArray erros = jsonObj.getJSONArray("errors");
    JSONObject error = erros.getJSONObject(0);
    String msg = error.getString("message");
    Log.d("Twitter Data", msg);
```

I am confused if to consider "errors" in the above json string as an object or an array.

Below is my logcat error:

```
02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: An                error      occured while executing doInBackground()
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity$FetchYoutubeVideos.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity$FetchYoutubeVideos.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    02-21 10:21:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  ... 4 more
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972): Activity com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40ce51d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,324} that was originally added here
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40ce51d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,324} that was originally added here
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity$FetchYoutubeVideos.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:56)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    02-21 10:21:09.731: E/WindowManager(972):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your json parsing is right

Comment: What is the value you're getting in the output? Are you getting any error? Because AFAICT the code looks pretty much fine to parse this JSON.

Comment: Yea I know that since I was able to parse the json data of example which  I was following. But wat i am doing in my MainActivity is that correct?

Comment: I am getting a RuntimeException telling error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Can you post the logcat output showing the RuntimeException?

Comment: @Mansoor what line number 77 in MainActivity.java.

Comment: Did you check that you are getting that JSON in JSONObject jsonObj = jsonParser.getJSONFromURL(twitterURL); ?

Comment: I dint check it. but since u mentioned it I logcat my jsonObj which I am receiving and its null. I thought my JSONParser was correct

Comment: Please debug before asking for a solution ! especially for NullPointer Exceptions !! waste of time !!!

Comment: yea i knw it was silly of me. I was actually very confident abt my getJSONFromURL() I was only concentrated on getting jsonObject and jsonArray. Sry to waste ur tym and appreciate ur help though Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The informative part is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.youtubevideolist.MainActivity$FetchYoutubeVideos.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
```

So you have a NullPointerException on that line.

If you don't already see the problem, you are welcome to mark the line in the code you posted and the folks here will tell you what could go wrong.

Comment: Yea I just checked i am getting null value from my getJSONFromURL(). I thought my JSONParser was correct. It works fine for the other json string y not fr this ?

Comment: You have in the code:
        if(statusCode != 200){
            return null;
        }
Maybe this makes it return null.

Comment: Which means the status code was not 200. But how can v get data if there was error connecting to webpage?

Comment: Status codes of the format 2xx are success codes! They dont have to be only 200!

Comment: its returning 400 in my case

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the string that is being returned from that method you have! A null string is being returned as far as my intuition goes.

I tried to following code and it worked

```
String jsonString = "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Bad Authentication data\",\"code\":215}]}";
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray erros = jsonObj.getJSONArray("errors");
JSONObject error;
error = erros.getJSONObject(0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Check the contents of the string before trying to parse the JSON

EDIT :

As a good practise always place a null check, especially since you explicityly have a line that can return a null string!